# Required annotation for webapi mvc4 fails for an integer property but works for string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, annotations, asp.net-web-api

When I make an ajax call, it fails with 500 Internal server error

```
Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)]
```

The problem is with CallerID property.

```
[Required]
public string AccountTypeID { get; set; }

[Required]
public int CallerID { get; set; }
```

If I mark CallerID as string, everything works well.
Any ideas why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known issue in Web API, you can see the whole history here:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/270

Basically, if you apply [Required] to a value type (such as bool or int, string is not a value type) it will cause this error.

Also you need to think about it - you are making `int` a required property - but as a value type it will always have value, value=0 even if it's not passed by the user. Perhaps you were thinking of `int?` instead?

You can either remove the `InvalidModelValidatorProvider` altogether (which may not be acceptable though):

```
config.Services.RemoveAll(
typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider), 
v => v is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);
```

Or just apply DataContract to your class:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass {

[DataMember(isRequired=true)]
public string AccountTypeID { get; set; }

[DataMember(isRequired=true)]
public int CallerID { get; set; }
}
```

One other workaround, mark the int as nullable:

```
[Required]
public int? CallerID { get; set; }
```

Comment: I totally missed **Value-Typed** part of the error message. Thanks for the explanation. Very much appreciate your time.

Comment: I don't believe the third option of marking the property as nullable works.  Anytime I use the `Required` attribute with an `int?` I get an exception: `Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required`.

Comment: Note:  Setting the `int` as `int?` nullable alone doesn't appear to resolve the issue.